# Delay when playing music with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot with `discord.js` and now that I'm implementing the `play` command (it uses a URL from youtube and plays the video). When I use the command the bot joins the voice channel but the audio starts playing after 2 or 3 seconds. I tried putting the command at the start of the code but it doesn't work either. This is the code:

```
        if (message.channel.type !== 'text' || args.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    
        if (!voiceChannel) {
            return;
        }
    
        voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
            const stream = ytdl(args[0], { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            dispatcher.on('end', () => voiceChannel.leave());
        });
```

Pd. `args[0]` contains the URL.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably waiting for youtube to buffer the beginning of the song. To confirm, you could add a console.log message that should trigger as soon as the channel is joined.

Comment: You're right, thanks